# Inject dependency in injected dependency with different InjectionConstructor parameters

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm using a helpful RestClient, which handles Rest-calls to other Webservices. This RestClient is part of bigger Service-Clients which handle different Webservices by providing convenience-methods which are used by the businesslogic etc..
I'm using UnityContainers for dependency-injection.

I've got some sort of RestClient:

```cs
public interface IRestClient
{
    T PostSomething<T>();
}

public class RestClient : IRestClient
{
    public RestClient(string baseUrl) { }
    public T PostSomething<T>() { /* post something */ }
}
```

Which i use in multiple ServiceClients:

```cs
public interface IServiceClient1
{
    void Work1();
}

public class ServiceClient1 : IServiceClient1
{
    private RestClient client;
    private string myRestUrl = "ServiceUrl1";

    public ServiceClient1(IRestClient client)
    {
        this.client = client;
        client.SetUrl(myRestUrl); // i don't want to do this here. This should be done by unity when RestClient is instantiated
    }
    public void Work1()
    {
        /* do something */
        client.PostSomething<string>();
    }
}

public interface IServiceClient2
{
    void Work2();
}

public class ServiceClient2 : IServiceClient2
{
    private RestClient client;
    private string myRestUrl = "ServiceUrl2";

    public ServiceClient2(IRestClient client)
    {
        this.client = client;
        client.SetUrl(myRestUrl); // i don't want to do this here. This should be done by unity when RestClient is instantiated
    }
    public void Work2()
    {
        /* do something */
        client.PostSomething<string>();
    }
}
```

Now I want to Inject those classes with UnityContainers:

```cs
container.RegisterType<IServiceClient1, ServiceClient1 >();
container.RegisterType<IServiceClient2, ServiceClient2 >();

// And here comes the problem:
container.RegisterType<IRestClient, RestClient>(new InjectionConstructor("ThisParameterShouldBeSetByServiceClient"));
```

Both `ServiceClients` are much more different as shown in this example. This example may only show the problem.

I want to register the type `RestClient` and I want that `ServiceClientX` selects the string-parameter for the Constructor of `RestClient`. And I don't want to set the Url in the Constructor of `ServiceClient`.

How can I achieve this with `UnityContainers`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a factory for this. If the ServiceClient decides how to create a RestClient:

```cs
public class ServiceClient1 : IServiceClient1
{
    private RestClient client;
    private string myRestUrl = "ServiceUrl1";

    public ServiceClient1(IRestClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        this.client = clientFactory.CreateClient(myRestUrl);
    }
    public void Work1()
    {
        /* do something */
    }
}
```

Unity injects the Factory and not the RestClient.

If the RestClient should be mocked the factory should be switched to a mock-factory.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what you figured out on your own, another approach is to use a `ParameterOverride` during the resolution.

```
container.RegisterType<IRestClient, RestClient>(url1, new ParameterOverride(url1));
IRestClient restClient1 = container.Resolve<IRestClient>(url1);
container.RegisterType<IServiceClient1, ServiceClient1>();
IServiceClient1 svcClient = container.Resolve<IServiceClient1>(
    new ParameterOverride("client", restClient1)
);
```

Comment: Good point, but this way the container has to be available when resolving.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you are mixing "inject dependencies" with "inject parameters".  If you code is new, then this is a less then ideal design.

With new code, you should (IMHO) inject DEPENDENCIES.

..

Now, how do you deal with your need?

There is a way.

Inject a IConfigurationRetriever into your ServiceClient1 and ServiceClient2.

```
public ServiceClient1 (IRestClient client, IConfigurationRetriever icr)
```

and now you can create a simple implementation

```
public interface IConfigurationRetriever()
{
    string GetSomeMagicValueOne();
}


public InMemoryConfigurationRetriever : IConfigurationRetriever
{
    public string GetSomeMagicValueOne(){ return "HardCodedUrl"; }
}
```

You shouldn't be hard coding URL's into the object.  But at least with the above, you have done the hard coding in a way that still keeps your ServiceClient1 and ServiceClient2 flexible for the future.

And how, when you want to create a different way to read configuration, you can write a "FromAppOrWebConfigConfigurationRetriever : IConfigurationRetriever" or "FromDotNetCoreJsonFileConfigurationRetriever : IConfigurationRetriever" or a "FromTheDatabaseConfigurationRetriever : IConfigurationRetriever"

IMHO, InjectionConstructor is used for dealing with "old code" that had parameters in the constructors as a work-around.  And InjectionConstructor should not be designed into new code.  Again, IMHO.